# How to set data type property as smalldatetime

Tags: c#, ado.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, code-first

Is there a way? The following doesn't work:

```
var customer = constructor.Entity<Customer>();
customer.Property(c => c.Date).DataType("smalldatetime");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
customer.Property(c => c.Date).HasStoreType("smalldatetime");
```

Answer (score 4):

My code first approach:

```
[Table("Customer", Schema = "DBSchema")]
public class Customer{

    [Column("Date", TypeName = "SmallDateTime")]   
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

}
```